# Anonymous users in firebase even without enabling

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I used firebase realtime database as backend of an online registration app for tech fest in my college.But I only enabled custom email and password authentication.But i found some users created account anonymously and it seems they were not able to sign as i restricted login only after email verification.But still how is it possible even after i made sure to disable anonymous authentication.

Comment: How did you find out anonymous users were created? Did they show up in your Firebase Console Users section?

Comment: yes.instead of email it was written "Anonymous" and the icon was also of a 'profile' icon instead of a 'mail' icon. But there was only created date.No signed in date.

Comment: Are you creating users via the Firebase Admin SDK by any chance?

Comment: Yes. Only using firebase admin SDK. Oh is it because some tries to create without using email?

Comment: Yeah if you create users from the admin SDK without credentials. They would be displayed as anonymous in the Firebase User console.

Comment: Thanks bojeil.Now I understand